# Creating an Executable Device in Java

Tags: redhawksdr

I am attempting to create an executable device with a single Java implementation in REDHAWK 1.9.

From the REDHAWK IDE I use **File** > **New** > **SCA Device Project**, and select **Executable** in the Device dropdown. For language I choose **Java** and the generator **Java Code Generator** using template **Pull Port Data**.

When I create the Device and generate the code in the IDE, it only extends `Device` which in turn only implements `CF.DeviceOperations`. I would have expected an executable device to extend something that implemented `CF.ExecutableDeviceOperations`. Looking at the source on [github](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/framework-core/tree/master/src/base/framework/java/ossie/src/org/ossie/component) there does not appear to be a Java Executable implementation.

I can run the Java Device in a Device Manager, but when I try to launch a waveform the Domain Manager prints the error:

```
Device <id> is not loadable
```

Looking at the source this appears to occur in the [Application Factory](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/framework-core/blob/master/src/control/sdr/dommgr/ApplicationFactory_impl.cpp?source=c#L2039) when it tries to narrow the device to a loadable device. My understanding is that a device must be loadable and executable in order to run a component, so it would make sense that it fails here if the implementation doesn't actually implement those methods.

If I change the implementation to C++ the generated code does extend an `ExecutableDevice_impl` that implements these functions, and I can use it to successfully load and execute a component from a waveform.

All this leads me to believe that a Java implementation of an executable device was not shipped with REDHAWK 1.9. Is this correct? Is one currently in development? I do not need to customize any of the methods that a GPP would provide for our hardware, so ideally I would reuse such an implementation if it existed.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  Only Java basic devices are currently supported in REDHAWK 1.8 and 1.9.  However, Loadable and Executable devices are supported in both Python and C++.